# How do I output conditional information in-place using ASP.net MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm completely new to ASP.net as well as MVC. I have a `foreach` loop to create some rows of information (displayed as horizontal lists). I want to have alternating class names for each row (dark and light).

I've read about `Response.Write()` however when I use that it seems to add this to the top of the output (immediately at the top of the document above the `<!DOCTYPE>`):

> `darklightdarklightdarklightdarklightdark...`

This is what I have so far:

```
@{
    // Dummy data.
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        <ul class="leader @{ Response.Write(i % 2 == 0 ? "light" : "dark"); }">
            <li class="rank">@i</li>
            <li class="challenger"><img alt="Photo" src="~/Content/Textures/Photo/temp-face.jpg" /> James Winters</li>
            <li class="date">01 Sept 2012</li>
            <li class="venue">NSW - Woolloomooloo Bay Hotel</li>
            <li class="points">2999</li>
        </ul>
    }
}
```

You'll notice that I've assumed `Response.Write()` was going to work in the same manner as PHP's `echo()`. What should I be doing instead?

(Note that there are alternate ways to achieve what I am doing here, I'm mainly using this as an example to ask about how to output information in-place in the HTML like I'm attempting).

This is MVC4 via the Visual Studio 2012 RC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Html.Raw helper for plain text output:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
        <ul class="leader @Html.Raw(i % 2 == 0 ? "light" : "dark")">
            <li class="rank">@i</li>
            <li class="challenger"><img alt="Photo" src="~/Content/Textures/Photo/temp-face.jpg" /> James Winters</li>
            <li class="date">01 Sept 2012</li>
            <li class="venue">NSW - Woolloomooloo Bay Hotel</li>
            <li class="points">2999</li>
        </ul>
}
```